# Separate numeric characters within a column in R

Tags: r

in r I have a column that shows age ranges like this:

```
Age <- c(1524, 2534, 3544, 4554, 5564, 65)
```

So, as in ages from 15 to 24, 15-34 ... and older than 65 years

I want the ages in my column to be separated by a "-". And the last age to say 65<". And look like:

```
Age <- c(15-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55-64, 65<)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture the first two characters (`(..)`) from the start (`^`) followed by the next two characters, insert the `-` between the backreferences of the captured group in replacement.  Then use `ifelse` to `paste` the element that doesn't have a `-` with `<`

```
Age <- sub("^(..)(..)$", "\\1-\\2", Age)
ifelse(grepl("-", Age), Age, paste0(Age, "<"))
#[1] "15-24" "25-34" "35-44" "45-54" "55-64" "65<"
```

---

Or may do this in a single step with `substr` and `sub`

1. Extract the first two characters - `substr(Age, 1, 2)`
2. Extract the next two - `substr(Age, 3, 4)`
3. Then, `paste` them together with a `-` in between
4. For those elements having only two characters, the second `substr` call returns `""`, thus we have `-` at the end of the string
5. Replace the `-` at the end (`$` - regex metacharacter for end of string) with `<`

```
sub("-$", "<", paste0(substr(Age, 1, 2), "-", substr(Age, 3, 4)))
[1] "15-24" "25-34" "35-44" "45-54" "55-64" "65<"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is:

1. Select the first two numbers of all elements in `Age` except the last one (65).
2. Paste the first two with '-' and the last two.
3. Append '65<' at the end.

```r
library(tidyverse)
Age <- c(1524, 2534, 3544, 4554, 5564, 65)

str_sub(Age[-length(Age)], 1, 2) %>% 
  str_c('-', str_sub(Age[-length(Age)], -2, -1)) %>%
  c(str_c(Age[length(Age)], '<'))
#> [1] "15-24" "25-34" "35-44" "45-54" "55-64" "65<"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>